# convert sublevel into a single column

Tags: python, pandas

```
Category                        Cat2    average  
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare  1       54.50
                                2       53.25
                                3       48.00
                                4       57.57
                                5       51.33
                                6       18.50
                                7       16.00
```

I have a dataframe, multilevel. I would need to convert the second level into a simple column. Would it be possible? `unstacking` creates columns 1 to 7.

As an addition: would it be possible to rename the group names (at level 0 and 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.reset_index(['Cat2'])` would convert the `Cat2` index to a column.

For example,

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
                                     average
Category                       Cat2         
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare 1       54.50
                               2       53.25
                               3       48.00
                               4       57.57
                               5       51.33
                               6       18.50
                               7       16.00

In [39]: df.reset_index(['Cat2'])
Out[39]: 
                                Cat2  average
Category                                     
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare     1    54.50
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare     2    53.25
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare     3    48.00
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare     4    57.57
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare     5    51.33
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare     6    18.50
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare     7    16.00
```

---

To change the index level names, use `df.index.names = ['foo', 'bar']`:

```
In [48]: df.index.names = ['foo', 'bar']

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
                                    average
foo                            bar         
Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare 1      54.50
                               2      53.25
                               3      48.00
                               4      57.57
                               5      51.33
                               6      18.50
                               7      16.00
```

Comment: Tnx. however,  df.reset_index(['Cat2']) somehow creates duplicates of the indices in 'df.index', therefore making it impossible to regroup by category.

Comment: Please post `df.info()` and `df.index`.

Comment: Index([u'Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare', u'Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare', u'Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare', u'Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare', u'Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare', u'Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare', u'Beauty / Wellness / Healthcare', u'Food & Drink', u'Food & Drink', u'Food & Drink', u'Food & Drink', u'Food & Drink', u'Food & Drink', u'Other', u'Other', u'Other', u'Other', u'Other', u'Other', u'Other', u'Other', u'Other', u'Other'], dtype='object')

Comment: I'm confused -- what is the problem? This shows you have an Index, not a MultiIndex. That means that `Cat2` is already a column.

Comment: The problem was that, to group by category, I needed to `df.reset_index(['Category'])` and then group again by `Category`. Problem solved. tnx

Comment: Ah, in that case, note that it is possible to groupby level values too: `df.groupby(level='Category')`.